# SQL function, extract numbers before -

Tags: sql-server-2005, user-defined-functions

i'm playing around with building a sql function that will extract numbers from a title, which is what the following code below does. Although, i want to modify this function to parse numbers into sections. For example:

Current Data in title field:

```
QW 1 RT 309-23-1
QW 1 RT 29-1
QW 1 RT 750-1
QW RT 750-1
```

Temp tables created once function is ran on title field:

```
column 1  Column 2  Column 3  Column 4
1         309       23        1
1         29        1         Null
1         750       1         Null
Null      750       1         Null
```

---

```
create function [dbo].[ExtractNumbers](@Numbers nvarchar(2000))  
returns nvarchar(2000)  
as 
BEGIN 
  declare @NonNumericIndex int  
  set @NonNumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Numbers)  

  WHILE @NonNumericIndex > 0  
  begin 
    SET @Numbers = REPLACE(@Numbers,SUBSTRING(@Numbers,@NonNumericIndex,1),'')  
    SET @NonNumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Numbers)  
    SET 
  end 

  return @Numbers  
END
```

Comment: Do all values have QW and RT?

Comment: ok then, is it always 2 letters each? help us to help you if it's important...

Comment: Yes, it's always two letters. Thanks for your input, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way.

Although actually at the end I realised the format was more fixed than I had originally realised so you may be better off just using the various string manipulation functions to calculate the columns directly.

```
WITH TestTable AS
(
SELECT 'QW 1 RT 309-23-1' AS title UNION ALL
SELECT 'QW 1 RT 29-1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'QW 1 RT 750-1' UNION ALL
SELECT 'QW RT 750-1' 
)
SELECT title, [1] AS [Column 1], [2] AS [Column 2],[3] AS [Column 3],[4] AS [Column 4]
FROM TestTable CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNumbers(title)
PIVOT 
(MAX(num) FOR idx IN ([1], [2],[3],[4])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Uses the following TVF

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetNumbers 
(
@Numbers NVARCHAR(2000) 
)
RETURNS @Results TABLE 
(
idx INT IDENTITY(1,1),
num INT
) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NonNumericIndex INT,  @NumericIndex INT

    SET @NumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Numbers)

    IF (@NumericIndex > 4) --First Column not there
          INSERT INTO @Results VALUES (NULL)

    WHILE @NumericIndex > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @Numbers = RIGHT(@Numbers,LEN(@Numbers)-@NumericIndex+1)

        SET @NonNumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',@Numbers)

        IF(@NonNumericIndex = 0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT
            INTO @Results VALUES (@Numbers)
            RETURN
        END
        ELSE
        INSERT
        INTO @Results VALUES
            (LEFT(@Numbers,@NonNumericIndex-1))

        SET @Numbers = RIGHT(@Numbers,LEN(@Numbers)-@NonNumericIndex+1)
        SET @NumericIndex = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@Numbers)
    END
    RETURN
END
```

Comment: wow, great input. it works good for the data that has a "1" at position 4 but titles such as 'QW RT 750-1' will put "750" into col 1 instead of a null.

Comment: It shouldn't do. I tested it with that. That's what the line `IF (@NumericIndex > 4)` is for. I'll just double check this end.

Comment: Nope definitely when I run the code in the post above it puts it into Column2 my end.

Comment: yes you're right, when the title inputs are hard coded in the select statement it runs correctly, but can it be tweaked to run on the title field dynamically? i have tons of records. i received the error when i just tried to run: 'SELECT title, [1] AS [Column 1], [2] AS [Column 2],[3] AS [Column 3],[4] AS [Column 4] 
FROM TestTable CROSS APPLY dbo.GetNumbers(title) 
PIVOT  
(MAX(num) FOR idx IN ([1], [2],[3],[4]) 
) AS PivotTable;' 
 .thank you so much for your post!

Comment: What error? Did you replace `TestTable` with the name of your table?

Comment: yes, i ran it on my table and the data was not parse out correctly for records most of the records.

Comment: @gates - Can you put it in another database that's set to a greater compatibility level and call it from your 2000 compatibility one.

Comment: what's interesting is that when i run the fuction on a table that only has the "title" field it works fine but when i run it on a table that has multiple fields that are text, it gives me the following error msg: Pivot grouping columns must be comparable. the type of colulmn "a text col name" is "text", which is not comparable."

Comment: Yopu might need to use `CAST(columnname as varchar(max))` to use it on text fields.

Comment: the title field alone isn't a problem. it's when title lives in a table with other fields.

Comment: Martin, did you try running the function against a table with more than one field?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Apply the function to more than one field at a time? If so you'll need a UNION as it wouldn't be able to share the output columns 1-4. If it is just the presence of the extra fields use a derived table. So instead of `FROM TestTable` it would be `FROM (SELECT title FROM yourtable) t`

Comment: hey martin, why does the function strip out duplicates? for example, if the data has two records with the title QW RT 750-1, only when will be returned.

Comment: nevermind, looks like i just have to add the record id for all records to show up...so that's working...

Comment: Hey martin, is it possible to display other table columns/fields within the same query. for instance, i would wrap the fuction on [title] but want the output view to be [title] [date] [desc] as i'm using the parsed fields to sort the list.

Comment: Yes. Just add them to the main Select list and the derived table select list. Both are keywords/reserved words so you might need square brackets around them `[date], [desc]`

Comment: ok, figured it out, you have to place the field names in both select statements. thanks again for everything.